# The order of words

Tags: word-order

I came across the following sentence on Memrise:

> Ich denke, es ist langweilig

and was confused because the verb *ist* does not go to end, like I thought it should.

Here is [another example](http://www.goal.com/de/news/839/primera-division/2012/12/17/3607550/tito-vilanova-ich-glaube-nicht-dass-die-liga-langweilig-ist):

> Ich glaube nicht, dass die Liga langweilig ist

Almost the same sentence, but now the verb is at the end.
I trust that both sentences are correct. Is it because of *dass?* Or is it not so strict in modern German?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the subclause conjunction, it is called an "uneingeleiteter Nebensatz", and the verb order is the same as in a main clause (verb second), even though it's a subclause.

There are similar rules for conditional and concessive subclauses without conjunction, see e.g. [the explanation in canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/uneingeleitet.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is a secondary sentence. It is a nearly complete sentence. Leaving the "dass" builds a short for of the sentence which has another sentence order.